# Callback smart pointer to this so object stays alive for the callback

Tags: c++, callback, c++17, smart-pointers

Up to C++17

I'd like to make sure that an object is alive for the duration of its callbacks being run.

That was the important bit. Consider a callback function that wants data from the object emitting the callback. Now I wish to keep the emitting object alive until said callback function has got what it needed. This might not be the case for all callbacks, not all callbacks deal with objects that might get deleted next.

This is what I came up with. Using named constructor idiom I can make sure that the created object is a shared_ptr, and then I can take a weak_ptr to that and so on.

I wonder if there is a better way around this?

```
// Example program
#include <memory>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

class Callback
{
public:
  using t_callback_func = std::function<void(std::shared_ptr < Callback>)>;
  using t_shared = std::shared_ptr<Callback>;
  std::vector<t_callback_func> callbacks;
  std::weak_ptr<Callback> uglyhax;

  static std::shared_ptr<Callback> make()
  {
    auto shared = std::shared_ptr<Callback>(new Callback());
    shared->uglyhax = shared;
    return shared; 
  }

  void register_callback(std::function<void(std::shared_ptr<Callback>)> && p_callback)
  {
    callbacks.emplace_back(std::forward<t_callback_func>(p_callback));
  }

  void notify()
  {
    if (auto shared = uglyhax.lock())
    {
      for (auto & callback : callbacks)
      {
        callback(shared);
      }
    }
  }

  void remove_callbacks()
  {
    callbacks.clear();
  }

  void hello()
  {
    std::cout << "hello " << this << "\n";
  }

  ~Callback() { std::cout << "dtor  " << this << "\n"; }

protected:
  Callback() { std::cout << "ctor " << this << "\n"; }

};

class EventList
{
  std::vector<std::function<void()>> events;
public:
  void call_events()
  {
    for (auto& event : events)
    {
      event();
    }
    events.clear();
  }

  template<class ...Args>
  auto wrap_as_event(std::function<void(Args...)> && p_func)
  {
    return [this, p_func](Args... args)
    {
      std::cout << "adding event\n";
      this->events.emplace_back(std::move(std::bind(std::move(p_func), std::forward<Args>(args)...)));
    };
  }
};

int main()
{
  EventList list;
  {
    {
      auto thing = Callback::make(); // I want to keep the thing allocated here alive until all its callbacks have been processed
      std::function<void(Callback::t_shared)> function = [](Callback::t_shared ptr) {ptr->hello(); ptr->remove_callbacks(); };
      thing->register_callback(list.wrap_as_event(std::move(function)));
      thing->notify();
    }
    std::cout << "dtor should be called after this\n";
    list.call_events();
  }
  std::cout << "dtor should be called before this\n";
}
```

Output:

```
ctor 013E81C0
adding event
dtor should be called after this
hello 013E81C0
dtor  013E81C0
dtor should be called before this
```

Comment: So many confusing aspects of this. In my head there is many better ways of doing this... but I'm guessing the complexity comes from requirements that are not clear from the question maybe?

Comment: *"Using named constructor idiom, I can make sure that the created object is a `shared_ptr`"*. You also have to protect against copy constructor.

Comment: Maybe you should show some code of the original problem that you're trying to work around. It's far from clear. It's very clear that this is a big ball of mess though. :-)

Comment: The gist is that I want to keep the source object alive until it's callbacks have been processed. So that anyone interested in its data can still access it.

Comment: Is `uglyhax` used to avoid [`std::enable_shared_from_this`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/enable_shared_from_this)?

Comment: enable_shared_from_this is new to me, I'll take a look. I don't know yet. Looks quite promising! thanks! Write it as an answer and you have my upvote I think :)

Answer (score 0):

You can separate the logic of event execution from the event and the event payload object.

The `Callable` is inheriting `enable_shared_from_this<Callable>` which allows safe creation of additional `shared_ptr`. The factory method getCallable will create an instance of Callable on the heap which is prerequisite for the `enible_shared_from_this` to work.

The `Callable` class knows how to generate the events and how to register it's `shared_ptr` to the `CallableEvent` that is specialized class of `Event`. The `Event` is then sent to the `EventHandler` which will process the event.

```
// Example program
#include <memory>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class Event;
class Callable;
class CallableEvent;

class Event {
public:
    virtual void trigger();
};

class EventHandler {
public:
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Event>> eventList;
    static EventHandler& getInstance() {
        static EventHandler instance = EventHandler();
        return instance;
    }

    void registerEvent(std::shared_ptr<Event> event) {
        eventList.push_back(event);
    }

    void processEvents() {
        for (auto event : eventList) {
            event->trigger();
        }
    }
};

class CallableEvent : public Event, public std::enable_shared_from_this<CallableEvent> {
public:
    using t_callback = std::function<void(std::shared_ptr<Callable>)>;
    std::shared_ptr<Callable> callable;
    t_callback callback;

    void trigger() override;

    CallableEvent() { std::cout << "Callable Event Created " << this << "\n"; }
    ~CallableEvent() { std::cout << "Callable Event Destroyed " << this << "\n"; }
};

class Callable : public std::enable_shared_from_this<Callable> {
public:
    int _payload;
    void registerEvent(std::function<void(std::shared_ptr<Callable>)> lambda) {
        std::shared_ptr<CallableEvent> ev = std::shared_ptr<CallableEvent>(new CallableEvent());
        ev->callable = shared_from_this();
        ev->callback = std::move(lambda);
        EventHandler::getInstance().registerEvent(ev);
    }

    static std::shared_ptr<Callable> createCallable(int payload) {
        return std::shared_ptr<Callable>(new Callable(payload));
    }

    void sayThis() {
        std::cout << "Hello from Callable "<< this << " my payload is " << _payload << "\n";
    }

    ~Callable() {
        std::cout << "Callable destroyed " << this << " with payload " << _payload << "\n";
    }

private:
    Callable(int payload) {
        _payload = payload;
        std::cout << "Callable created " << this << " with payload " << _payload << "\n";
    }
};

void Event::trigger() {
    std::cout << "generic event \n";
}

void CallableEvent::trigger() {
    callback(callable);
}

int main()
{
    {
        {
            auto cb = Callable::createCallable(15);
            CallableEvent::t_callback function = [](std::shared_ptr<Callable> ptr) {
                std::cout << "Calling from lambda\n";
                ptr->sayThis();
            };
            cb->registerEvent(function);
        }
        std::cout << "Callback should be called after this\n";
        EventHandler::getInstance().processEvents();
  }
  std::cout << "Callback should be called before this\n";
}
```

When running the example the output the following output is generated:

```
Callable created 0x7f89f4c057d0 with payload 15
Callable Event Created 0x7f89f4c05810
Callback should be called after this
Calling from lambda
Hello from Callable 0x7f89f4c057d0 my payload is 15
Callback should be called before this
Callable Event Destroyed 0x7f89f4c05810
Callable destroyed 0x7f89f4c057d0 with payload 15

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Now you can move the handler to another thread and the events will be executed asynchronously.

Comment: eh? I was asking how to keep the object sending the callback alive, I don't understand this answer. I'll make the question clearer.

Comment: Yes, this is the idea what I'm aiming for. The example is just simplified. It's almost too complex already.

Comment: @0xbaadf00d I think I got the idea, but let me clarify the goal: You will have some code that will generate events and associated callback objects. You want the events to be processed prior the callback are deallocated. Do you need them to be processed before certain time and do you need the results from the callback in the context where you had generated the callback handler?

Comment: I'd like the freedom to have the creator of the callback be capable of deciding. That's why I used shared_ptr as it's thread safe itself. Context might change, the callback has void return type, so the originating component can't get any result through it. Basically I want the callback objects to keep the originating object alive. As long as the callback object is itself alive.

Comment: Ok, I understood the intention, it was not very clear from the example the first time I went trough it. You need the `shared_ptr` to keep the object destroyed after it leaves the context. If you move away from smart pointers, you will need to manage the memory by yourself. One alternative to smart pointers is to use Factory object to create the Callback and pass it back by reference which will keep the factory as owner of the callback object. You will tell the Factory when the object is no longer needed to release it. I will think more on this and update the answer with example

Comment: @0xbaadf00d *Basically I want the callback objects to keep the originating object alive.* Create a lambda that captures a `std::shared_ptr` of whatever resource it needs to keep alive by value. (If the resource is indeed a shared thing, otherwise just capture the resource by value).

Comment: Is this not what I did in my example? I'm confused.. The problem I had is that how do I create a shared pointer in this context? I chose to use a weak_ptr from which I copy it. If i create two separate instances of shared_ptrs to an object, the first one to reach 0 refcount kills the object, no?

Comment: @0xbaadf00d you did explain, I am confused from the need to create the Callback in the context. The Callback is the handler of the events, I would go with approach to have him as singletone global object and then registering the callbacks as needed. I don't see the reason for having more than one instance of it. Allow me some time to prepare example of wha I mean and  we can discuss it afterwards.

Comment: @0xbaadf00d No. you made a lambda that takes a `std::shared_ptr` as an input argument. Instead just capture the `std::shared_ptr` by value and the callback will keep it alive as long as it exists.